# Swift: Best way to manage UI elements, such as UIButtons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, label

I'm new to Swift.

I'm trying to make template files for all elements that I often use such as buttons and labels.

Can you tell me the best way manage the templates like that has the appearance like including the colors, corner radius?

I cannot figure out except using Class files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do it.

1 - create your own class

```
final class PrimaryButton: UIButton {

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       backgroundColor = UIColor.red
       setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
   }
}
```

2 - create extension to configure

```
extension UIButton {
    func style() {
        backgroundColor = R.color.primary()
        setTitleColor(R.color.black(), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

and call this function in viewDidLoad

first style is preferred

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to create a new file called "Styling" with the same-named class.
Then, inside there, I create static functions that accept parameters that you want to edit (for example, button).

```
class Styling {
   static func styleButton(_ button: UIButton) {
      button.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
   }
}
```

Then I just call it by typing in vc:

```
Styling.styleButton(myButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answers what works for me is putting series of buttons in an array of UIButtons. It makes it much simples to rearrange them while developing the app or adjusting to various screens.

Here is a simplified example of 12 buttons forming a colorful flag:

```
var flagButton: [UIButton] = []
for i in 0...11 {
flagButton.append(UIButton())
flagButton[i].frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
self.view.addSubview(flagButton[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    }

}
```

And use it:

[image]